# Most cost efficient way to page through a poorly ordered table?

Tags: sql-server, pagination

I have a table that has three columns:
HashUID1, HashUID2, Address_Name (which is a textual email address, and the previous two hash colunms are of some crazy creation to link event participant tables to email addresses. its ugly, it barely works its out of my control. Focus on the address_name index)

It has 78 million rows. Not properly sorted. Regardless, this index is split onto a lot of fast LUN's and performs REALLY fast index seeks.

I need to create a series of queries to extract only 20,000 "rows per page" at a time, but avoid conflicts or dupes. Since there is no identity column, **or easily ordered column,** is there an easy way to select all, and page through it?

Am I correct in saying that if I do a select * from hugetablewithemails into a temp table, then select through it by row_number that the table remains in memory for the duration of the transaction, which, to me, is an excessive amount of memory resources?
This seems the preferred method of paging. I'd rather page by statistical percentages. :(

There is one index which maintains the address_name email address in order, and is well maintained. For the past week I have been meaning to help this other developer by spending some time on looking into building a proc that spits out ranges based on windowing functions based on statistics (which I am not great at, but this query really interested me) to provide a range of characters 1 through (variable) LEFT LIKE chars of the index, that meets 20,000 rows--But I have not had time to even start the query...

Couple questions:

1. Any suggestions? Not looking for actual code, just some hints or suggestions based on experiences, maybe caveats. I want to avoid additional index scans after the initial scan.
2. Is this the right approach?
3. I'm thinking of breaking the sum of the index of all email addresses, gathering rowcount(*), /20,000, and usinng that as a windowing function to group min/max substring(1,5) values based on percentages of total rowcount to build grouping ranges. Thoughts?

This is for an ETL process that cannot modify source databases.

I am hoping with one full index scan I can do a:

- Query to get a histograph based on index usage (alphabetically sorted) and break it out (windowed) using min/max to create some ranges like this, so to easily seek the needed index:
- A-> AAAX, (20k rows for example) AAA-Z, B-> (another 20k), B->BAAR -> BAAR-> CDEFG -> CDEFH > FAAH, etc.

We run read committed in these databases for this ETL process. We are only attempting to batch it out in scores of 20k rows because the DBA's say we are using too much network resources by grabbing tables in full. If the data has changed (which is a concern) we update our DW and staging tables on the fly.

I would *love* to use temp tables, but if I did, I'd spill into tempdb and get lashings via e-mail from the DBAs regarding it, and that the database is too big.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Essentially, you are asking if you can perform a single ordered scan through the data overall, while making no copies of the data, and returning 'x' disjoint sets of rows from the full set on each call. This is exactly the behaviour of an appropriately-configured API cursor.

For example, using the AdventureWorks table `Person.EmailAddress` to return sets of 1,000 rows:

```
DECLARE 
    @cur integer,
    -- FAST_FORWARD | AUTO_FETCH | AUTO_CLOSE
    @scrollopt integer = 16 | 8192 | 16384,
    -- READ_ONLY, CHECK_ACCEPTED_OPTS, READ_ONLY_ACCEPTABLE
    @ccopt integer = 1 | 32768 | 65536, 
    @rowcount integer = 1000,
    @rc integer;

-- Open the cursor and return the first 1,000 rows
EXECUTE @rc = sys.sp_cursoropen
    @cur OUTPUT,
    N'
    SELECT *
    FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.EmailAddress
        WITH (INDEX([IX_EmailAddress_EmailAddress]))
    ORDER BY EmailAddress;
    ',
    @scrollopt OUTPUT,
    @ccopt OUTPUT,
    @rowcount OUTPUT;

IF @rc <> 16 -- FastForward cursor automatically closed
BEGIN
    -- Name the cursor so we can use CURSOR_STATUS
    EXECUTE sys.sp_cursoroption
        @cur, 
        2, 
        'MyCursorName';

    -- Until the cursor auto-closes
    WHILE CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'MyCursorName') = 1
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE sys.sp_cursorfetch
            @cur,
            2,
            0,
            1000;
    END;
END;
```

Each fetch operation returns a maximum of 1,000 rows, remembering the position of the scan from the previous call.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the purpose behind the windowing it's going to be difficult to be specific.  Considering you're looking at twenty thousand rows at a time, I'm guessing this is a batch process and not for human viewing.

If there is an index on the email address then it *is* sorted.  Indexes are BTrees and they maintain an order internally.  This will be the sort order of the collation of that column (which is likely, but not necessarily, the default colation of the database).

Temporary tables - both #table and @table - will have a presence in tempdb.  Also large resultsets will spill out of memory to tempdb.

If by "statistics" you mean SQL Server's internal statistics it maintains on indexes or through the `create statistics..` statement then I don't think that will fly.  Those statistics only have a few hundred buckets (forgotten the correct limit just now) where as you will need 39,000 "windows" to read read your full table.  If you intend to maintain your own row-to-window mapping through triggers, this is achievable but the overhead may be significant.

The traditional way to page through a large dataset is by remembering the largest key value from each group and reading from there onward.  If the email address column is not unique i.e. one address can occur more than once you have a couple of options.  A) process each batch row-by-row in the application and skip duplicates or b) filter them out in the SQL.  "B" will require a sort but if the data is read in key sequence this sort may be optimised away:

```
declare @MaxKey varchar(255) = '';  -- email size

while exists (select 1 from mytable where address_name > @MyKey)
begin
    ;with NewBatch as
    (
    select top 20000  -- whatever size a "window" must be
        address_name
    from mytable
    where address_name > @MaxKey
    order by address_name
    )
    select distinct
        address_name
    from NewBatch;

    --process and then
    select @MaxKey = max(address_name) -- from this batch of rows
end
```

The itteration can happen in SQL or your applicaiton, depending on your architeture.

If many columns are requied, other than just the email address, you may consider a cursor with the KEYSET or STATIC keyword defined.  This will still use resources in tempdb, however.

Taking a step backward, SSIS is specifically designed to process large rowsets efficiently.  Defining a package that meets your requirements may be the best long-term answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply concerned with sort order stability over time in the presence of DML consider using Snapshot Isolation to query the table. You can leave a `SNAPSHOT` transaction open until you are done extracting pages. This has the usual drawbacks associated with Snapshot Isolation.

That said this technique will require sorting the entire table for each page you extract. That is really expensive (quadratic asymptotic performance).

Consider using a temp table with an `IDENTITY` primary key. That way you can easily extract pages through range seeks.

Temp tables are not pinned into memory. This is a common misconception.

With 78m rows (each 100 bytes => 7.8GB of disk space) this technique should work fine.

Note, that extracting the data from the original table using, for example, `READ COMMITTED` might give you a data set that never existed at any point in time (due to concurrent DML). Use `SNAPSHOT` isolation if you can.

You can create the temporary table in your own database or in a separate SIMPLE-mode, not backed up database. Also note, that sorting the entire table is going to temporarily use as much tempdb space as it takes to store all the columns you need. So maybe you need to derive the row numbers from the already existing (unique) index (and apply the size reduction trick).

---

Another idea: Instead of buffering all rows to the temp table, only write a key of each row. You indicated that seeks in them main table would be fast.

Or, you only write every 20,000th row so that you know where to start each paging query. Extracting a page would then not work by row number but with `SELECT TOP 20000 ... WHERE SomeKey >= PageStartKey ORDER BY SomeKey`.